# Methods that allow me to change a QwtPlot color background

Tags: c++, qt, qwt

I would like to know what methods I can use to change my QwtPlot after it has been created and also how to use. By now I'm using QwtPlot->setCanvasBackground() in my constructor, however in my program the user have the option to change the background color of the plot with  some others graphical options that are all setted in a specific method that belongs to class that inherits from QwtPlot. Any advices? Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Qt StyleSheets](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/stylesheet.html). The following code sets the canvas background color to gray:

```
    QwtPlotCanvas { background: #888888; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option to change the QwtPlot canvas color:

```
plot->setAutoFillBackground(false);
plot->canvas()->setPalette(color);
```